# PrimeNG Calendar how to handle timezones <p-calendar>

Tags: angular, date, primeng

I have an issue while using  with PrimeNG where I have multiple users using a form that are in different timezones; however, I want all the users of the for to submit their form calendar in EST. It seems though that when the form is submitted no matter what date/time they choose it is being converted to the browsers/users timezone. How is this disabled or implemented? so that when the form is submitted through a JSON object that it just keeps one static timezone (GMT)

**Current Code**

**Form HTML**

```
<p-calendar required [(ngModel)]="entry.reportedDate" name="reportedDate" #reportedDate="ngModel" [showIcon]="true" [showTime]="true" dateFormat="mm/dd/y 'EST'" hourFormat="24"></p-calendar>
```

[image: Front End]

**json object**

```
{"reportedDate": "2019-02-13T15:00:16.000Z"}
```

**FrontEnd HTML**

```
<td style="border-right:3px solid #a5d891;">{{ m.reportedDate | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, y, HH:mm'}} EST</td>
```

So when my other timezone user uses this form the reportedDate will adjust to their timezone and I don't want that to happen.

I just ONE standard timezone date that is passed from the json object to my backend and then rendered to the front end without manipulation

Hope this makes sense, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

PrimeNG does not have let you specify the time zone. 
You can however do your own calculation to get your desired timezone, and submit that value.

For example, you can use 
`new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` to get the use's time zone offset, and add the difference to EST time to the Date Value.

Also, you should use `<td> {{ m.reportedDate | date: 'EEEE, MMMM d, y, HH:mm':'-500' }} EST  </td>` to display the time in EST time.